# For loop to repeat and increment day number in code

Tags: php, for-loop, count

I need loop some code trough 24 times to create a 24 day Christmas calendar. I have the for loop below but how do i add the '$i' to the code to make sure the wherever there is a day number it changes from 1 through to 24 each time? What would the code look like?

```
        <?php for ($i = 1; $i < 25; $i++) { ?>


          <!-- DAY 1 -->
          <a href="offer.php?day=1<? echo '&dealership='. $dealership; ?>" class="item <? if ($today[mday] == 1) { echo "current yellow"; } else if ($today[mday] < 2 ) { echo "disabled"; }?>">
            <div class="offer">
                    <h2>Day 1</h2>
                    <p><? echo Day_1_Offer('CAL_OFFER'); ?></p>
                    <? echo $termsLink; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="offer-img">
              <img src="img/day1.jpg">
            </div>
          </a>


        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: `<h2>Day <?= $i ?></h2>` and `<img src="img/day<?= $i ?>.jpg">` maybe?

Comment: Concatenate/echo it like you do for example with $dealership?

Comment: `$today[mday]` << whats that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `<?php echo $i; ?>` whenever you need the number.

```
      <!-- DAY 1 -->
      <a href="offer.php?day=<?php echo $i; ?><? echo '&dealership='. $dealership; ?>" class="item <? if ($today[mday] == 1) { echo "current yellow"; } else if ($today[mday] < 2 ) { echo "disabled"; }?>">
        <div class="offer">
                <h2>Day <?php echo $i; ?></h2>
                <p><? echo call_user_func('Day_'.$i.'_Offer', 'CAL_OFFER'); ?></p>
                <? echo $termsLink; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="offer-img">
          <img src="img/day<?php echo $i; ?>.jpg">
        </div>
      </a>


    <?php } ?>
```

To modify the Day_1_Offer call you must do a things a bit differently, as it's a function and in the PHP and not part of the HTML. To do this, you need [call_user_func()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php). Try this:

```
<p><? echo call_user_func('Day_'.$i.'_Offer', 'CAL_OFFER'); ?></p>
```

Comment: can I do that to the function `Day_1_Offer`?

Comment: so how do i increment `<p><? echo Day_1_Offer('CAL_OFFER'); ?></p>`?

Comment: @Amesey Edited to include this.